# Yocto: Failure expanding variable KERNEL_LOCALVERSION

Tags: yocto, texas-instruments

I am facing below error while building kernel from local workspace(created by `devtool modify virtual/kernel`). If I do not have workspace created then I don't see any error.

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.10.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Var <KERNEL_LOCALVERSION>", line 1, in <module>
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable KERNEL_LOCALVERSION, expression was -g${@d.getVar('SRCPV', True).split('+')[1]} which triggered exception IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you help me on resolving this? I need to have workspace since I am working on kernel related changes. I am using `dunfell` branch of `meta-ti`.

```
Loading cache: 100% |#########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 4480 entries from dependency cache.
WARNING: /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.10.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for do_configure
WARNING: /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.10.bb: Error during finalise of /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.10.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.10.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Var <KERNEL_LOCALVERSION>", line 1, in <module>
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable KERNEL_LOCALVERSION, expression was -g${@d.getVar('SRCPV', True).split('+')[1]} which triggered exception IndexError: list index out of range

WARNING: /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-ti/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.4.bb: Cooker received SIGTERM, shutting down...
WARNING: /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-carrier/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging_4.19.bb: Cooker received SIGTERM, shutting down...
WARNING: /home/aws-fsp-build/rax-workspace/yocto/meta-carrier/recipes-kernel/mstp-mod/mstp-mod.bb: Cooker received SIGTERM, shutting down...

Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like after moving to the workspace, the SRCPV variable changes formatting, which leads to parsing failure. Try to add something like this to the build/workspace/appends/linux-ti-staging-rt_5.4.bbappend file:

```
KERNEL_LOCALVERSION = "-g999"
```